# Where did the socket for GitLab-workhorse go?

Tags: nginx, gitlab, nginx-reverse-proxy, gitlab-ce

The /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/ folder is missing a socket and is generally almost empty.

I'm trying to set up GitLab + nginx proxy. When I try to load the page, I get a 502 error.
Having figured out what exactly does not work for me, I realized (gitlab-ctl status):

`down: gitlab-workhorse: 0s, normally up, want up; run: log: (pid 3756258) 12450s`

Then I decided to look at my workhorse socket and this is what I saw in the /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse folder (ls -ap /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/):

`./  ../  config.toml  VERSION`

My gitlab settings:

```
nginx['enable'] = false
web_server['external_users'] = ['www-data']
gitlab_rails['trusted_proxies'] = ['127.0.0.1', <external-server-ip>]
gitlab_workhorse['listen_network'] = "unix"
gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket"
```

nginx log:

`connect() to unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream`

As I understand it, I am missing the required software or some files. Where can I get them if that's the problem. If not, why might my workhorse not work?

p.s. sorry for google translate :)

upd. (/var/log/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/current):

```
{"build_time":"20221024.191252","level":"info","msg":"Starting","time":"2022-10-30T20:05:21+03:00","version":"v15.5.1"}
{"address":"localhost:9229","level":"info","msg":"Running metrics server","network":"tcp","time":"2022-10-30T20:05:21+03:00"}
{"level":"info","msg":"keywatcher: starting process loop","time":"2022-10-30T20:05:21+03:00"}
{"address":"/var/opt/gitlab/redis/redis.socket","level":"info","msg":"redis: dialing","network":"unix","time":"2022-10-30T20:05:21+03:00"}
{"address":"/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket","level":"info","msg":"Running upstream server","network":"unix","time":"2022-10-30T20:05:21+03:00"}
{"error":"listen unix /var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket: bind: no such file or directory","level":"fatal","msg":"shutting down","time":"2022-10-30T20:05:21+03:00"
```

Comment: Try to create `sockets` folder in `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse` folder and give permissions for gitlab-workhorse to create files there

Comment: Did not help :(

Comment: Log of what site do you look in nginx logs? Your gitlab install has option `nginx['enable'] = false`. And check please logs of gitlab-workhorse - may be there are lines about opening the unix socket

Comment: @AlexanderUshakov Unfortunately, the gitlab-workhorse log shows that it cannot find the socket file (I added its log to the upd.). Regarding nginx: I looked at the log of my proxy server, which cannot proxy due to the fact that the gitlab-workhorse is not working. A complete reinstall of gitlab didn't help.

Comment: Do you really need to use path `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket` for gitlab_workhorse unix socket? Try something like `gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "/tmp/gitlab-workhorse-socket" for test

Comment: No, I don't care. For some reason I thought it was important for gitlab. I tried and it worked! Should I just leave it in the /tmp/ directory and isn't it dangerous?

Comment: The place of socket isn't important. For example MySQL creates its socket in /tmp folder too. To keep all things in one place you can try to create socket in root gitlab-workhorse directory: `gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket"`

Comment: As it helped to solve your problem I've added an answer to the question. Feel free to accept and like it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change path to socket in `listen_addr` setting to existing directory.

For example `gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket"` or `gitlab_workhorse['listen_addr'] = "/tmp/gitlab-workhorse-socket"`

Answer (score 1):

For me, I had upgraded to 15.5, and saw this in the nginx error log:

`connect() to unix:/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream`

Looks like the gitlab folks changed the path of that socket file from `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/socket` to `/var/opt/gitlab/gitlab-workhorse/sockets/socket`.

Change the path in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/gitlab` and then run `nginx -s reload && systemctl restart nginx` (OR change the path like previously suggested in `gitlab.rb` and run `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.

Comment: The fact it was moved from gitlab-workhorse/sockets/private/ to gitlab-workhorse/sockets/sockets/ helped me. This suggested I check if it was in the directory above /private/.